# Android onClickListener and Button only fires once

Tags: java, android, onclick, onclicklistener, android-button

UPDATE: Solved, the problem was in my activity_main.xml
Ive updated my code below to reflect the changes I made.

I will make one more post updating my .java file with the proper way to handle text scrolling with out a ScrollView, described by deathember.

---

UPDATE:
I changed commented out the lines `this.terminal.append("Button# clicked...\n");` and added `this.terminal.setText("Button# clicked...");` which behaved as expected and changed  the text with each button press, no problems.

With this I know my buttonClicked method is being called, the text isn't being appended to the TextView though, any suggestions on how to solve this?

---

I've checked the other posts encountering this problem, but all the solutions seemed specific to their app.

I have a TextView inside a ScrollView, to give the behaviour similar to that of a terminal, with 4 Buttons that when clicked append text to the TextView saying they've been clicked.

However, I only get click events once. I can click any of the buttons and it displays that the correct button was clicked, but any subsequent clicks are not noticed by the app.

---

My Android Activity Main .java

```
package com.drj.pokemonar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView        terminal;
    ScrollView      terminalSView;

    Button          button1;
    Button          button2;
    Button          button3;
    Button          button4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.terminal       = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputTerminal);
        this.terminalSView  = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.outputScrollView);

        this.button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        this.button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        this.button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        this.button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

        // Necessary to bring the view to the bottom when
        //  a new line is appended.
        this.terminalSView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ScrollView sView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.outputScrollView);
                sView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
            }
        });

    }

    // Defines the buttons behavior when clicked.
    public void buttonClicked(View v)
    {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.button1:
        {
            this.terminal.append("Button1 clicked...\n");
            break;
        }
        case R.id.button2:
        {
            this.terminal.append("Button2 clicked...\n");
            break;
        }
        case R.id.button3:
        {
            this.terminal.append("Button3 clicked...\n");
            break;
        }
        case R.id.button4:
        {
            this.terminal.append("Button4 clicked...\n");
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            break;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

---

My Android Activity Main .xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/outputScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/outputTerminal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="" />

        </ScrollView>

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:onClick="buttonClicked" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"                    
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:onClick="buttonClicked" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:onClick="buttonClicked" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:onClick="buttonClicked" />

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Im not sure why this is happening. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: If you first click button 1 and then button 2, are they both added to the terminal?

Comment: Setting the scroll with focus down may be pulling focus from your buttons to the scrollview itself? Try removing your runnable section and just see what happens. (Just to test).

Comment: @MaxMeijer No, subsequent button presses aren't added. If I click button2, it correctly shows it was clicked. Then click button1, nothing. Same thing happens no matter which button is clicked. Only the first click is handled by the listener.

Comment: @zgc7009 Ill give that a try then get back to you.
Edit: I commented out that section of code to no affect. Behaviour remains the same, only it doesnt scroll down.

Comment: Update, the buttonClicked method is being called for each button press, however the TextView is not appending the text. I tested this by calling setText on the TextView, instead of append, and it worked as expected. Not sure what to do from here though.

Comment: Instead of doing append do terminal.setText(terminal.getText() + "button x clicked...\n");? Shot in the dark on that one as append should pretty much do that

Comment: @zgc7009 That gives the effect I desire, but should such a bandage solution really be necessary? I would rather solve the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code which does the trick for you :)

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView terminal;
    Button button1, button2, button3, button4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        terminal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputTerminal);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    }

    // Defines the buttons behavior when clicked.
    public void buttonClicked(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:

            terminal.append("Button1 clicked...\n");
            break;

        case R.id.button2:

            terminal.append("Button2 clicked...\n");
            break;

        case R.id.button3:

            terminal.append("Button3 clicked...\n");
            break;

        case R.id.button4:

            terminal.append("Button4 clicked...\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I see Now How it might be messing up with you. Please change the TextView in your Layout to like below:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/outputTerminal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />
```

And check the code now. Comment back if any issues.

Comment: Sorry, didn't solve it. The only thing it did is prevent it from auto scrolling. In case I'm missing something, did you do anything else besides remove all uses of terminalSView from the onCreate method and remove the default case from the switch statement?

Comment: I've also used terminal.append(); and removed run() which is not required.... I request you to copy n paste my entire code in to your activity_main.java file and see how it works. I tested it at my side and it's working perfectly.

Comment: I copy pasted your code, compiled fine, no change in behaviour, didn't solve the problem. Could the problem be caused by my emulator, or the android libraries?

Comment: Looks like you are messing up with the TextView in your layout file. I've put the modified TextView. Please use it in your XML file and check with the final run. Once success, I can clarify if any doubts...

Comment: Cool. You don't have to complicate your code with unnecessary RunonUIThread...blah...blah...unless it is must needed. As it's a simple use case :), made the code simple for you. Welcome to Android Programming....

Answer (score 1):

To scroll the **TextView** is not necessarily housed inside **ScrollView**, **TextView** can scroll itself. Need to change the layout of **TextView**, adding attribute

```
android: scrollbars = "vertical"
```

activity and change the code, setting scrolling method

```
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod; 

... 

mTexView.setMovementMethod (new ScrollingMovementMethod ());
```

and **ScrollView - remove.**

Example based on Skeleton App of the Android SDK. Instead add EditText TextView:

```
<TextView android: id = "@ + id / editor" 
     android: layout_width = "match_parent" 
     android: layout_height = "0dip" 
     android: autoText = "true" 
     android: capitalize = "sentences" 
     android: layout_weight = "2" 
     android: freezesText = "true" 
     android: textSize = "120dip" 
     android: scrollbars = "vertical"> 
</ TextView>
```

### Working code :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView        terminal;
    ScrollView      terminalSView;

    Button          button1;
    Button          button2;
    Button          button3;
    Button          button4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        this.terminal       = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputTerminal);
        terminal.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        this.button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        this.button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        this.button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        this.button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    }

    // Defines the buttons behavior when clicked.
    public void buttonClicked(View v)
    {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.button1:
            {
                this.terminal.append("Button1 clicked...\n");
                break;
            }
            case R.id.button2:
            {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        terminal.append("Button2 clicked...\n");
                    }
                });
                break;
            }
            case R.id.button3:
            {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        terminal.append("Button3 clicked...\n");
                    }
                });

                break;
            }
            case R.id.button4:
            {
                this.terminal.append("Button4 clicked...\n");
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView android:id="@+id/outputTerminal"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:autoText="true"
                      android:capitalize="sentences"
                      android:layout_weight="2"
                      android:freezesText="true"
                      android:textSize="12sp"
                      android:scrollbars = "vertical" >
            </TextView>
        <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Button"
                        android:onClick="buttonClicked" />

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Button"
                        android:onClick="buttonClicked" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button3"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Button"
                        android:onClick="buttonClicked" />

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button4"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Button"
                        android:onClick="buttonClicked" />

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Result :

[image: result :]

Comment: The ScrollView isn't whats causing the problem. The TextView simply isnt appending the text, and its boggling my mind as to why. See my comments on Ramakishna Balla's answer

Comment: @0x0byte Did you try my example?

Comment: Ill give it a try. Could you explain the use of the runOnUIThread methods? and why only 2 of the buttons contain them?

Comment: @0x0byte i do it for example. First idea of my mind - you set a value from separate background thread but that idea was wrong.